# How to change google map default style

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

How to change google map from its default style. I need some light gray style,
This is my code.

```
jQuery(function($) {
// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
    ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
    '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>']
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

}
```

I got some code when I search on google. But I have no idea where to put this styles into my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        }
      ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style Google Maps with their API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252632/how-to-style-google-maps-with-their-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `styles` array within your `mapOptions` variable, like so:

```
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    styles: [...]
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can set the `icon` property of your marker to the filepath of an image for a custom marker.

More here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons

Answer (score 1):

**Add style to `mapOptions`**

Read more on how to style your map at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

```
jQuery(function($) {
// Asynchronously Load the map API 
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function initialize() {
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        }
      ]
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
    ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
    ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
    '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
    '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
    '</div>']
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
```